# Very slow refresh when changing styles

Tags: css, reactjs, meteor, coffeescript, stylus

I'm using `coffeescript` and `coagmano:stylus`.
When I import the styles inside the stylus files (`@import './some/path/style.styl'`) it works fine.
But when I import the styles inside the coffee files (`import './style.styl'`) then hot reload doesn't work, with each change of styles the project is rebuild and the page reloads and besides this refresh has long delays, 20 - 60 seconds.

Comment: What Os are you using?

Comment: MacOS Mojave. I also tested it on Windows 10 and Ubuntu, and it has the same problem.